# Input button click event

Tags: html, asp.net, button, input

I have input button and on this button I write some code. I select data from table and display in grid view when I click on  button, but when I select data from drop down and then when I click on button then button event no call?

I need to display data when I click on button

How can I do this?
Here's my code:

```
protected void search_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //query
}

<input type="button" ID="search_data" runat="server" class="sear_btn"  value="Search Data" onclick="search_data_Click" />
```

Comment: use j query: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: i don't want to use jquery.. there is linq i used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OnServerClick`

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" runat="server" id="btnSave" OnServerClick="search_data_Click" />
```

Comment: when i click nothing happens